# Como forzar permanencia del Focus en un EditText en Android?

Tags: android, android-studio

**Hola**

Tengo el problema que quiero forzar o hacer que el **Focus** en un **EditText** se mantenga siempre activo en cualquier momento en la actividad, porque al yo limpiar **EditText** u actualizar un **recycleView** este pierde el Focus del teclado y lo peor es que el teclado queda activo pero no el **Focus** y si activo el **Focus** se pierde la funcionalidad del teclado.

**Trate de solucionar con esto en el xml del EditText:**

```html
           <EditText
            android:id="@+id/edittext_chatbox"
            android:hint="Ingresa tu Mensaje"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:focusable="true"
            android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:maxLines="6"/>
```

**En el codigo al obtener un perdida del focus lo activo de nuevo con esto:**

```
edit_mensaje.setOnFocusChangeListener(new View.OnFocusChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
                if (!hasFocus) {
                    edit_mensaje.clearFocus();
                    edit_mensaje.requestFocus();
                    InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
                    imm.showSoftInput(edit_mensaje, InputMethodManager.SHOW_IMPLICIT);
                }

            }
        });
```

Pero de una forma extraña el anterior código hace que el teclado no funcione. **También agregue en el manifests de mi activity:**

```html
<activity android:name=".ActivityChat"
  android:windowSoftInputMode="stateVisible"
  android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden"/>
```

Sin embargo despues de todo esto no funciona. Lo que busco es lo que tiene por ejemplo **WhatsApp** que mantiene la el **EditText** siempre con su Focus activo. **Necesito su apoyo.**

El método mencionado en los comentarios ya no me es válido porque uso un RecycleView el cual actualmente a cargar ya sea un view que contiene solo un textview le quita el Focus al editText o al simplemente actualizar el recycle este le roba el Focus.

Comment: No termino de entender tu pregunta, quieres que tu `EditText` mantenga el foco sin importar lo que se haga, ¿Verdad? Pues si eso es lo que quiere, primero deberías crear un método para ocultar el teclado cuando se inicia la `activity` y se segundo asignarle el foco cuando se presione sobre el `EditText`. Por último deberías configurar el `onBackPressed` para que cuando se presione se oculte el teclado.

Comment: Perfecto amigo esto es lo que de verdad necesito.

Comment: Que bueno que te haya servido :)

Comment: Si me coloca una respuesta se la acepto amigo

Comment: En ves de el showimplicit del keyboard dale show force , hay una opcion de forzar.

Comment: LA PREGUNTA es como actualizar tu recycler y como limpias un editText, no deberia perderse el focus. -.-

Comment: Simplemente en el editText simplemente hago esto ´input.setText(" ");´ y con el recycle el metodo ´adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();´ en su adaptador personalizado

Comment: Simplemente en el editText simplemente hago esto ´input.setText(" ");´ y con el recycle el metodo ´adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();´ en su adaptador personalizado

Answer (score 1):

Primeramente debes asegurar esconder el teclado virtual y posteriormente enfocar la vista.

**Esconder teclado virtual**:

Para esto puedes usar el siguiente método que recibe la Activity en la cual muestras el teclado virtual:

```
public static void hideKeyboard(Activity act) {
    if (act != null) {
        InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) act.getSystemService(Activity.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
        if (imm != null) {
            View view = act.getCurrentFocus();
            view = (view == null) ? new View(act) : view;
            imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(view.getWindowToken(), 0);
        }
    } else {
        Log.e("Error", "can't hide Keyboard null activity!");
    }
}
```

Para obtener el enfoque en la vista usa el método  `.requestFocus()` :

```
 edit_mensaje.requestFocus();
```

Comment: Entonces primero escondo el teclado, luego lo enfoco pero al momento de querer escribir ? Es decir al momento que el usuario quiera usar el editText. Lo que quiero es algo como WhatsApp que al entrar pareciera que nunca perdiera el enfoque y siempre está activo el editText

Comment: @Abraham.P en el momento que el usuario quiera usar el EditText se mostrará el teclado virtual. Te sugiero entonces no realices requestFocus() para el EditText.

Comment: Amigo su solución me sigue fallando porque al momento de cargar otra vista al recycle falla

Comment: Cuando presentes una falla, comenta que error es el que se presenta, o comenta en que consiste la falla por favor.

Comment: Te explico amigo no hay fallo visible por consola, sino que el focus del EditText, después que se añade un nuevo hijo al recycleView.

Comment: Necesitas el código del adaptador ?

Comment: Agregalo por favor para revisar

Comment: El problema es muy grande el código creo que StackOverflow.

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/116587/discussion-between-jorgesys-and-abraham-p).

Comment: Vale amistad espero su ayuda